Is health as much a philosophical question as a medical question?
This website, "Philosophy", directly deals with cultural attitudes to violence and to sex.  I believe we are desensitized to violence through media coverage, entertainment, sports, the prominence of defense budgets, war departments and institutions, the current portrayal of hatred and violent rhetoric on social media.  We seem to tolerate such violence simply by not forbidding it from political discourse (First Amendment), allowing disinformation and misinformation on opposing news media (MSNBC/Fox), having difficulty using filters effectively on social media platforms like FB and X and Truth Social, celebrating sports where violence to bodies is common, buying entertainment where violence is expected to resolve conflicts or display power differences.
As for pleasure, acceptance of it seems to be aimed at fine food, drink, dining, vacation resorts, travel, holidays, family celebrations, but not portrayals of sexual pleasure.  It is true that YouTube has many podcasts, descriptions and advocacy venues for sexual experiences that are viewed positively.  (See Dr. Lindsey Doe on Sexplanations on YouTube, for example.)  It is also possible to see many cautions against SDIs, how to have safe sex, sexual identities simply by Googling those interests on YouTube or Google or Bing or other internet browser.  But I haven't noticed much public dialogue on the importance of sexual pleasure for addressing widespread loneliness, depression, variations in sexual drive, inhibitions and other primary sexual functions and dysfunctions.  Of course, "sex is complex".  But if it is also vital to our physical and emotional health, why isn't it more acceptable?  Making it taboo or shameful or forbidden,just increases its power over us, in my opinion.

Sounds like more of a question of sociology or something, rather than philosophy.

I like other people.   Sex may or may not be part of a healthy relationship for me.

When I was a kid I often cringed at violence in TV shows that appeared daily (even with only a few channels available). Yet I lacked exposure to information about sex and depictions of healthy relationships until adulthood. Sex seemed like it would and should play a much larger role in my life than violence, yet we still have this strange bias. Hearing that in most other countries, the bias was reversed, nude beaches were visited by families routinely and guns were rare only made me think that I had been born in a very strange place.

When you discuss the issue in terms of general philosophy, you are advised to start with a big picture.
"How does personal sexual pleasure fit with the short-term goals of our World (Simulator)?"

Does it help in the overarching goal of technological progress?
Does it stimulate people's drive to improve their inherited intelligence level?
...


Similar questions for violence?
